# Installing Sharepoint on Windows 7

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop. I want to know what is the best way to install MOSS 2007 on my laptop?

- I heard that MOSS 2007 can be directly installed on Windows 7. I want to know if there are ny problems if I do this
- Or should I install Windows SErver 2008 on VM and then install MOSS 2007 on Windows Server 2008. Is it possible to install Windows Server 2008 VM on Windows 7??

Please let me know the best option...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- MOSS 2007 can be installed on Windows Vista/7 but it's not supported and at your own risks (here is the link but it doesn't work righ now: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/21/how-to-install-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-sp1-on-vista-x64-x86.aspx)
- It is possible to installed Windows Server 2008 on Windows 7, but you'll need a x64 version of 2008. You'll have to use VMWare or Virtual Sunbox which will need a lot of extra ressources.

Unless you have a really powerful computer, the best choice is a dual boot Win7 / Windows 2008.

Note: With SharePoint 2010, it is supported to install SharePoint directly on Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.Can i use Virtual PC 2007 to install Windows Server 2008???

Comment: No, you can't. Virtual PC can't host a x64 OS.